# PyTorch loop through epoch then output final values for all epoch

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch

The code below calculates the MSE and MAE values but I have an issue where the values for MAE and MSE don't get store_MAE and store MSE after the end of each epoch. It appears to use the values of the last epoch only. Any idea what I need to do in the code to save the values for each epoch I hope this makes sense. Thanks for your help

```
    global_step = 0
best_test_error = 10000
MAE_for_all_epochs = []
MSE_for_all_epochs = []
for epoch in range(4):
    print("Epoch %d" % epoch)
    model.train()
    for images, paths in tqdm(loader_train):
        images = images.to(device)
        targets = torch.tensor([metadata['count'][os.path.split(path)[-1]] for path in paths]) # B
        targets = targets.float().to(device)

        # forward pass:
        output = model(images) # B x 1 x 9 x 9 (analogous to a heatmap)
        preds = output.sum(dim=[1,2,3]) # predicted cell counts (vector of length B)
        
        # backward pass:
        loss = torch.mean((preds - targets)**2)
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

        # logging:
        count_error = torch.abs(preds - targets).mean()
        writer.add_scalar('train_loss', loss.item(), global_step=global_step)
        writer.add_scalar('train_count_error', count_error.item(), global_step=global_step)

        print("Step %d, loss=%f, count error=%f" % (global_step,loss.item(),count_error.item()))

        global_step += 1
    
    mean_test_error = 0
    model.eval()
    for images, paths in tqdm(loader_test):
        images = images.to(device)
        targets = torch.tensor([metadata['count'][os.path.split(path)[-1]] for path in paths]) # B
        targets = targets.float().to(device)

        # forward pass:
        output = model(images) # B x 1 x 9 x 9 (analogous to a heatmap)
        preds = output.sum(dim=[1,2,3]) # predicted cell counts (vector of length B)

        # logging:
        #error = torch.abs(preds - targets).sum().data
        #squared_error = ((preds - targets)*(preds - targets)).sum().data

        #runnning_mae += error
        #runnning_mse += squared_error

        loss = torch.mean((preds - targets)**2)
        count_error = torch.abs(preds - targets).mean()
        mean_test_error += count_error
        writer.add_scalar('test_loss', loss.item(), global_step=global_step)
        writer.add_scalar('test_count_error', count_error.item(), global_step=global_step)
        
        global_step += 1
        #store_MAE = 0
        #store_MSE = 0

        mean_test_error = mean_test_error / len(loader_test)
        #store_MAE += mean_test_error
        MAE_for_all_epochs = np.append(MAE_for_all_epochs, mean_test_error)

        mse = math.sqrt(loss / len(loader_test))
        #store_MSE +=mse
        MSE_for_all_epochs = np.append(MSE_for_all_epochs, mse)

        print("Test count error: %f" % mean_test_error)
        print("MSE: %f" % mse)

    if mean_test_error < best_test_error:
        best_test_error = mean_test_error
        torch.save({'state_dict':model.state_dict(),
                    'optimizer_state_dict':optimizer.state_dict(),
                    'globalStep':global_step,
                    'train_paths':dataset_train.files,
                    'test_paths':dataset_test.files},checkpoint_path)

print("MAE Total: %f" % store_MAE)
print("MSE Total: %f" % store_MSE)
model_mae= MAE_for_all_epochs / epoch
model_mse= MSE_for_all_epochs / epoch
print("Model MAE: %f" % model_mae)
print("Model MSE: %f" % model_mse)
```

Comment: should probably tag `pytorch` on this one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`np.append()` will work for your case like this,

```
#outside epochs loop
MAE_for_all_epochs = [] 

#inside loop
#replace this store_MAE with relevant variable

MAE_for_all_epochs = np.append(MAE_for_all_epochs, store_MAE)
```

Edit: Toy example: as per the usage

```
import numpy as np
all_var = []

for e in range(1, 10):
    var1 = np.random.random(1)
    all_var = np.append(all_var, var1)
    
print(all_var)
# output : [0.07660848 0.46824825 0.09432051 0.79462902 0.97798061 0.67299183 0.50996432 0.13084029 0.95100381]
```

Comment: I have updated my code with your answer, but I am getting a Traceback message: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train3_Eval.py", line 160, in <module>
    MAE_for_all_epochs = np.append(MAE_for_all_epochs, mean_test_error)
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 6, in append

Comment: your variable mean_test_error is a pytorch variable not numpy. use `numpy()` function to convert tensor to numpy as `mean_test_error.numpy()` and you will be good to go

Comment: I have the following error message: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train3_Eval.py", line 177, in <module>
    print("MAE Total: %f" % MAE_for_all_epochs)
TypeError: must be real number, not list

Comment: simple use `print(MAE_for_all_epochs)` and it will print you the list

Comment: Thanks. This prints a list of tensors. I would like to be able to sum those numbers then multiply by the number of the epochs. How do I convert the list into a single number which is the sum all the number, please? Thanks for your help

Comment: MAE_for_all_epochs.sum()